# How to write excel formula using only MIN-MAX, without IF

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, min

I need to rewrite below Excel formula without using IF. I suppose I can create it with using nested MIN & MAX.:

```
> IF(A1>2.8,1,0)
```

Comment: You can write `=(A1>2.8)+0` as well! Is this an assignment?

Comment: `=(A1>2.8)*1` will return the number values of the boolean result.

Comment: Thanks a million! I thought too complex... No, this is not an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple options to convert a boolean result to numerical equivalent 1 or 0.  Basically send the boolean through a math operation that does not changes its value.  Below is a basic list of some common options.

```
=--(A1>2.8)
=(A1>2.8)^1
=(A1>2.8)/1
=(A1>2.8)*1
=(A1>2.8)+0
=(A1>2.8)-0
```

note this is not the same as using a function such as SUM or PRODUCT